# Vue component is not rendered in the project without any further error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have simple Vue app, but my components is not rendered. It is just a test app, created over vue-cli

main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
//import router from "./router";


import 'bootstrap'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.js'

createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <Footer></Footer>
</template>

<script>
import './assets/stylesheets/custom.css';
import {defineAsyncComponent} from "vue";

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Footer: defineAsyncComponent(() =>
        import('./footer/Footer')
    )
  }
}
</script>
```

components/footer/Footer.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Test</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Footer'
}

</script>
```

But my component is unable to load, I don't know how to set the path to import the component properly.

I tried many variants of path

`./footer/Footer`  with components, src etc.

Comment: I set up a project just like this and pasted in your same code, the only change I needed was to fix the path for the footer component. I had to use ./components/footer/Footer but it renders as expected. Odd. If you want to, we can [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227849/chad)

Comment: I tried to create one more time from scratch, it is working now. But when I use async component it displays nothing, without async is working well, I don't know where was mistake. Thanks for assurance

Comment: very odd. I definitely managed to use exactly your code, just with the changed path. So odd. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for help! You helped me to find the solution, because I know there is something strange happening and my code is ok. Thanks